# How many racks of lamb can be made into a crown roast?

Tags: lamb

I am serving 6 adults for Christmas dinner, and have 4 racks of lamb, each about 1.25-1.5 lbs. I believe 3 racks will be enough, but I bought another just in case.

Is it possible to make 4 racks into one crown roast, or will it be too big? What about 3 racks? Should I not cook 4 racks at one time in the oven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the amount will matter too much for cooking, just may take a bit longer, but a thermotor should help there.

What I would consider doing is make the crown out of the three like you had planned and cook the fourth seperatly (but at the same time).  When the lamb is done carve the extra rack (by the single bone) and use it to garnish the crown either inside the crown poking out, or infront of the crown laying on their sides so everyone can see how perfect the lamb is cooked... so everyone will be impressed with both the pretty crown and how well the meat is perpared.

Comment: Sounds good. I typically wait to award an answer until it's proven in practice :)

Answer (score 0):

I've cooked up to 10 racks of lamb in my oven.  Now, if you think about it, this is not a huge amount for an oven to handle since farm-bred turkeys can be a similar or larger amount of meat.

Comment: I was worried less about total weight and more about uneven cooking. I agree, though.